# Why has stackexchange.com a different top bar

Tags: discussion, top-bar, stackexchange.com

Most StackExchange sites have picked up this new black top bar by now. One notable exception is the stackexchange.com page itself: the bar there has a different style, and no direct access to the inbox / reputation (/ hats). Furthermore, the hot questions list apparently keeps loading forever, so it doesn't seem to work properly any more. Is there some intention to replace that top bar as well soon?

Comment: In short: different codebase. As for hot questions, working just fine for me. Try hard refresh.